# pagination does'nt get updated on search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

Html Code: This is the html code that basically showas a table with search filter. . .

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search.$" />
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeSort('name')">User</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeSort('contentType')">Content Type</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeSort('contentName')">Content Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeSort('startTime')">Start Time</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeSort('endTime')">End Time</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeSort('duration')">Duration(In Secs)</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="record in records 
            | filter: search 
            | offset: currentPage*itemsPerPage 
            | limitTo: itemsPerPage 
            | orderBy:sort:reverse track by $index">
            <td>{{record.user}}</td>
            <td>{{record.contentType}}</td>
            <td>{{record.contentName}}</td>
            <td>{{record.startTime}}</td>
            <td>{{record.endTime}}</td>
            <td>{{record.duration}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <td colspan="6">
            <div class="pagination pull-right">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-class="prevPageDisabled()"><a href
                        ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a></li>
                    <li ng-repeat="n in range()"
                        ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage(n)">
                        <a href="#">{{n+1}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-class="nextPageDisabled()"><a href
                        ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Angular Js Code: This is the angular code using whtch search, sorting and pagination is done. . .

```
angular.module("contentViewStatusApp").controller("contentViewStatusController", function($scope, contentViewStatusService)
{
    $scope.records = contentViewStatusService.list();

    $scope.changeSort = function(value)
    {
        if ($scope.sort == value)
        {
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
            return;
        }
        $scope.sort = value;
        $scope.reverse = false;
    }

    $scope.itemsPerPage = 8;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.range = function()
    {
        var rangeSize = 5;
        var ret = [];
        var start;

        start = $scope.currentPage;
        if (start > $scope.pageCount() - rangeSize)
        {
            start = $scope.pageCount() - rangeSize + 1;
        }

        for (var i = start; i < start + rangeSize; i++)
        {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function()
    {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0)
        {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.prevPageDisabled = function()
    {
        return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";
    };

    $scope.pageCount = function()
    {
        return Math.ceil($scope.records.length / $scope.itemsPerPage) - 1;
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function()
    {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount())
        {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPageDisabled = function()
    {
        return $scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount() ? "disabled" : "";
    };

    $scope.setPage = function(n)
    {
        $scope.currentPage = n;
    };
});
angular.module("contentViewStatusApp").filter('offset', function()
{
    return function(input, start)
    {
        start = parseInt(start, 10);
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});
```

The only problem I am facing here is pagination doesnt get updated after search when the number of records reduce, any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of items in your records array never changes because filter returns a new array, not an updated version of the source array. Therefore, pageCount does not change either; in order to solve this, two possible solution :

- The easiest way to solve this is probably to programmatically filter your data in you controller. Supposing you passed the $filter service to your controller, you can write a function :

  $scope.getFilteredRecords = function() {
      var filterBy = $filter('filter');
      return filterBy($scope.records, $scope.search);
  }

Then use getFilteredRecords() instead of records in both your viewer and pageCount(); this is the easiest way but will do multiple redundant filters ; this might be a performance issue if you have a lot of data

- A more efficient way to achieve a similar result is to use the $watch service, which checks whenever a given variable changes value. You can thus $watch any change in $scope.search, populate a secondary variable filtered and use it instead of records :
  somewhere in your controller (but not inside a function), register your $watch :

  var filterBy = $filter('filter');
  $scope.$watch('search', function (newValue) {
      $scope.filtered = filterBy($scope.records, newValue);
  }, true);

Update your view :

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in filtered
            | offset: currentPage*itemsPerPage 
            | limitTo: itemsPerPage 
            | orderBy:sort:reverse track by $index">
```

(you don't need filter anymore since $watch will take care of that)

Update pageCount :

```
$scope.pageCount = function()
    {
        return Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length / $scope.itemsPerPage) - 1;
    };
```

Comment: Isn't the offset filter just trimming the array to the current items on the page? The range function is what sets the pagination?

Comment: OP's issue, as I understand it, is that pagination does not change when search criteria are updated and the filtered list gets smaller (which should result in less pages). This has nothing to do with the offset filter, just the search filter. You're right, the range function is responsible for the pagination. But it is based on pageCount(), which in turns looks at $scope.records, which never gets updated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am trying to go by the second method, but in is not working, can u tell me the places where i need to make the changes